# Aggregate function with Expr in PySpark 3.0.3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate, apache-spark-3.0

The following code works well with `PySpark 3.2.1`

```py
df.withColumn(
    "total_amount",
    f.aggregate(f.col("taxes"), f.lit(0.00), lambda acc, x: acc + x["amount"]),
)
```

I've downgraded to PySpark **3.0.3**. How to change the above code to something like this:

```py
df.withColumn(
    "total_amount",
     # f.aggregate(f.col("taxes"), f.lit(0.00), lambda acc, x: acc + x["amount"]),
     f.lit(expr("aggregate(taxes,0,(acc,x)->acc+x['amount'])"))
)
```

`x['amount']` does not work in our case! Is there something wrong the expression or I must change the **taxes** to have a list of numbers?

### 2nd case

```py
df.withColumn(
            "total_amount_2",
            f.aggregate(
                f.filter(
                    "lines",
                    lambda x: (
                        x["id"].isNotNull()
                        & (
                            x["code"].isin(["CODE1", "CODE2"]) == False
                        )
                    ),
                ),
                f.lit(0.00),
                lambda acc, x: acc + x["amount"],
            ),
        )
```

---

How to refactor these cases using **spark.sql expr** function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. I'm certain that one can access struct fields using dot notation too. I'm just not sure about the data type that you use (`0.00`), as this should be of the same data type as before. I have added the `D` letter which indicates it's a double.

```py
df.withColumn(
    "total_amount",
    F.expr("aggregate(taxes, 0D, (acc, x) -> acc + x.amount)")
)
```

Regarding the 2nd case, review the following test case. I have tested it using Spark 3.0.3.

Input df:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [([('1', 'CODE3', 3.0), ('2', 'CODE3', 3.0)],)],
    'lines: array<struct<id:string,code:string,amount:double>>'
)
```

Script:

```py
df = df.withColumn(
    "total_amount_2",
    F.expr("""
        aggregate(
            filter(
                lines,
                x -> x.id is not null and !x.code in ('CODE1', 'CODE2')
            ),
            0D,
            (acc, x) -> acc + x.amount
        )
    """)
)
df.show(truncate=0)
# +----------------------------------+--------------+
# |lines                             |total_amount_2|
# +----------------------------------+--------------+
# |[[1, CODE3, 3.0], [2, CODE3, 3.0]]|6.0           |
# +----------------------------------+--------------+
```